# Output the text from a docx file to a text area

Tags: javascript

I want to take the text from a docx file and and put it as the value of a textarea when a user clicks a button? I know how to create a button, change value of the textarea and so on, what I can't figure out is how to take the text from the docx file, with formatting elements if possible. And I need to mention that I GET the docx file from an external server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you can do using :[Docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/goals.html)

Things to remember:

If you are directly downloading the file from [build](https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#browser) and not from cdn as used in this script, then you will have to create `new Docxtemplater()` instead of `new window.docxtemplater()`;

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var zip = new JSZip(reader.result);
    var doc = new window.docxtemplater().loadZip(zip);
    var text = doc.getFullText();
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = text;
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/docxtemplater/3.1.9/docxtemplater.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.6.1/jszip.js"></script>
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'>
<br>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```